# How to prevent auto-mounting a specific SATA drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, sata

I'm trying to recover data from a laptop drive using ddrescue. After first getting slow speeds via an external USB case, I connected it directly via SATA inside the desktop computer.
However, according to the ddrescue info page:
"If you interrupt the rescue and then reboot, any partially copied
partitions should be hidden before allowing them to be touched by any
operating system that tries to mount and "fix" the partitions it sees."

So how can I prevent the auto-mounting of the laptop drive in the desktop computer?
I have no UUID for use in /etc/fstab and since the drive is already so broken it won't mount, I don't know how to get any from it.

Or does the note from the manual only concern the copy generated by ddrescue (an image file in my case), not the original source drive?

Note: The laptop drive is partitioned.

fdisk -l output:

```
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/sdb: 698.7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc59815e4

Device     Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048   31459327  31457280    15G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb2  *     31459328   31664127    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3        31664128  747739135 716075008 341.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       747739136 1465145343 717406208 342.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: There is automount and `fsck -p` only for devices in `/etc/fstab`. If device is not listed, it will be left alone.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that kind of makes my question invalid, while solving my worries. Do you want to put that in as an answer? (Sorry for the late reply. I stopped the ddrescue operation over the christmas holidays because it was just too slow. I might try again soon with an internal destination drive to maximize speed.)